# Reason for the `Object.prototype` setter being called when setting an array index property

Tags: javascript, chromium

Given the following code:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, '0', { // Will behave similarly if we define on `Array.prototype`
    configurable: true,
    get: function () {
        console.log('prototype getter accessed');
        return this['_0']; // Allow continued testing
    },
    set: function (v) {
        console.log('prototype setter accessed');
        console.log('setValue', v);
        this['_0'] = v; // See getter above
    }
});

console.log('creating array with 0 index pre-set');
var a = ['a'];

var b = [];

console.log('pushing to empty array to set 0 index');
b.push('b');

var c = [];

console.log('Setting 0 index directly on empty array');
c[0] = 'c';

var d = ['d'];
console.log('Setting 0 index directly on non-empty array');
d[0] = 'dd';
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...the following console output is shown in Chrome:

```
creating array with 0 index pre-set
pushing to empty array to set 0 index
prototype setter accessed
setValue b
Setting 0 index directly on empty array
prototype setter accessed
setValue c
Setting 0 index directly on non-empty array
```

In other words, what has apparently happened is that when an item is added to the array (after it has already been created), Chrome will for some reason go up the prototype chain, though even more oddly, not to get the property but to set it.

I would like to know whether this is a bug or where in the spec this behavior is defined.

(And FWIW, in attempting to allow setting on the array in a different manner, with the following, infinite recursion occurs from the mere defining of the property:

```
var e = [];
Object.defineProperty(e, '0', {configurable: true, writable: true, enumerable: true, value: 'got 0'});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you access this property using `c['0']`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: `c[0]` and `c['0']` access the same property. Property names are never actually numbers; the `0` in `c[0]` is coerced to string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but with an array isn't the property '0' is different to the item 0?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: No, it isn't. Standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).

Comment: I'm still a little confused at to what the problem statement of this question?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I think the main question is why accessing `c[0]` doesn't trigger the property getter. And the answer is interesting (I'm writing it now).

Comment: Sorry, not `c[0]`, `d[0]`.

Comment: Brett - Did you need further clarification of the answer below?

Comment: Looks like a great answer--and part of my problem itself was actually some "brain fog" and being so focused on the setting of the "own" property that I blanked out that the setting could go further down the prototype chain... Not feeling well today, but aim to take a closer look and credit the surely deserving answer once I can genuinely look it over... :)  Thanks! (As I have energy, I might also describe what I think you might find an interesting reason I'm asking all this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is in-spec, although it looks like Chrome is largely on its own getting it right (Firefox and IE11 don't). The key thing here is that setting `theArray[0]` *during* array creation (your `a` and `d` examples) is different from setting it afterward (your `b` and `c` examples; more on that in a moment). It's down to how array initializers are processed.

> In other words, what has apparently happened is that when an item is added to the array (after it has already been created), Chrome will for some reason go up the prototype chain, though even more oddly, not to get the property but to set it.

It does for `get`, too; you just don't have any `get`s in your code, and what you would see would vary depending on which of your arrays you did the `get` on (you'd see the getter run for `b` and `c`, but not `a` or `d`). The reason for the variation is that you've created `"0"` as an **own** property on `a` and `d`, but on `b` and `c` it's an inherited property with a getter/setter. We see the getter triggered if we access `b[0]`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, '0', { // Will behave similarly if we define on `Array.prototype`
    configurable: true,
    get: function () {
        console.log('prototype getter accessed');
        return this['_0']; // Allow continued testing
    },
    set: function (v) {
        console.log('prototype setter accessed');
        console.log('setValue', v);
        this['_0'] = v; // See getter above
    }
});

var b = [];

console.log('pushing to empty array to set 0 index');
b.push('b');

console.log("accessing b[0]");
console.log(b[0]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

#### What's Going On

Standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)*, they're objects that use the `Array.prototype` and have special handling for a class of property names ("array indexes") and the `length` property. That explains the majority of what you're seeing, since you're triggering `get` and `set` operations with property `"0"`.

The crux of your question seems to be why accessing `d[0]` doesn't trigger the getter/setter. The answer is: Because `d` has an **own** property called `"0"` rather than using the inherited one from `Object.prototype`. The reason for that is that you created `d` like this:

```
var d = ['d'];
```

The processing of an array initializer doesn't set properties through the prototype chain. If we look at [ArrayInitialization](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) in the spec, we see that it processes the properties in the initializer via the [ArrayAccumulation operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation), which does an interesting thing: It goes directly to [CreateDataProperty](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-createdataproperty) to add the properties instead of the more typical [PutValue operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-putvalue). CreateDataProperty doesn't traverse the prototype chain, it directly creates a data property on the object.

So that means there's a big difference in the `"0"` property for

```
var b = [];
b.push('b');
```

and

```
var d = ['d'];
```

`d` has an **own** property which is a simple data property. `b` has an **inherited** property with a getter/setter.

We can easily prove that to ourselves:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, '0', { // Will behave similarly if we define on `Array.prototype`
    configurable: true,
    get: function () {
        console.log('prototype getter accessed');
        return this['_0']; // Allow continued testing
    },
    set: function (v) {
        console.log('prototype setter accessed');
        console.log('setValue', v);
        this['_0'] = v; // See getter above
    }
});

var b = [];
b.push('b');
console.log("b.hasOwnProperty(0)? ", b.hasOwnProperty(0));

var d = ['d'];
console.log("d.hasOwnProperty(0)? ", d.hasOwnProperty(0));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Those last two `console.log`s show us:

```
b.hasOwnProperty(0)?  false
d.hasOwnProperty(0)?  true
```

That's because the array initializer bypassed the prototype chain to create a `"0"` property on `d`, but we didn't do that with `b`. So what we have in memory (details omitted) is:

```
                                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
Object.prototype−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−>|    (object)     |
                                                  |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                  |  | get 0: function |
                                                  |  | set 0: function |
                                                  |  | ...             |
                                                  |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                  |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
Array.prototype−−−−−−−−−−−−−++>| [[Prototype]] |>−+
                           //  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                          / |
                          | |
                          | |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | |
b−−−−−>|    (array)    |  | |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | |
       | [[Prototype]] |>−+ |
       | length: 1     |    |
       | _0: "b"       |    |   * Notice this is _0, not 0
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
                            |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
d−−−−−>|    (array)    |    |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
       | [[Prototype]] |>−−−+
       | length: 1     |
       | 0: "d"        |
       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note how `b` has the `"_0"` property (created by the setter), but not the `"0"` property (which it inherits from `Object.prototype`). But `d` has its own `"0"` property.

---

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Comment: I guess you could have just said "arrays are objects" and found a duplicate about inherited getters/setters being shadowed by own properties, but +1 nonetheless

Comment: @Bergi: :-) Thanks. That wouldn't have explained *why* `a` and `d` got own properties while `b` and `c` got the inherited one, though.

Comment: Maybe accompanied by a link to a question about JSON hijacking :-)

Comment: It is a helpful answer to myself as well as others, so marking as such, but I may post another to better spell out my issue when I have a chance.